# How do you define custom objects in-line in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, inline

I'd like to define a psuedo strongly typed object but still be able to define it inline.

current solution:

```
callMethod({param1:paramvalue,param2:paramvalue2});
```

I'd like to use similar inline syntax but the parameter 'object' to only contain a specific list of parameters.  IE: only allow param1 & param2 but not param3.

I'd be happy with something like this:

```
callMethod(mytype(param1:paramvalue,param2:paramvalue2);
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot for asking this question because IMMEDIATELY after posting it i thought... I can od this.. It's just:

callMethod(new MyType(paramvalue,paramvalue2));

*sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
callMethod( new MyType(paramvalue, paramvalue2) );
```

Comment: posting this here for completeness. accept it and you'll get some rep back atleast ;)

Comment: The answer is marked as community wiki, so I get nothing, you, however got a massive 5 reputation points. Score!